# ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my **server windows 2003** the default language and installation is in **english** language.

Now I need show the GridView of my aspx page in **spanish language**.

I have tried this *code-behind* but the output in GridView is always in english and I have error even when I try to run the **query strSQL**, why?

```
ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. 
The connection's current state is closed.
```

My code below.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.
Thank you in advance.

```
public DataTable GridViewBind()
{
    sql = " SELECT * from .... ; ";

    try
    {
        dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        dset = new DataSet();
        dset.Clear();
        dadapter.Fill(dset);
        DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;

        string strSQL = " SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'; ";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(strSQL, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        GridView1.DataBind();

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        dadapter.Dispose();
        dadapter = null;
        conn.Close();
    }
}


protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    Page.Culture = "es-ES";
    Page.UICulture = "es-ES";
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        InitializeCulture();
        GridViewBind();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
conn.Open();
string strSQL = " SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'; ";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(strSQL, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The error message states what the problem is. Your connection is closed. It has to be open.

Comment: thank you, I have **EDIT** 1 in my first post, the error now is The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Comment: I posed a question below but, apparently it does not answer the question so it has been deleted! I want to include some code from the OP's post - you can't do that easily in these comments boxes.

So, how can you help if you can't query the code? I don't want to edit the OP's code - that would just be confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're opening connection before using it in `OdbcDataAdapter` or `OdbcCommand`

```
conn.Open();
```

Comment: thank you, I have **EDIT** 1 in my first post, the error now is The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. 
The connection's current state is closed." your current connection status is closed, please open connection before using it using conn.Open() method